# Typescript how to extend interface with keys from array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

On a scenario to have a *pointfree* `omit` i can do this:

```
type PlainObject<T> = {[key: string]: T}

const omit = <K extends string>(
  name: K
) => <T, U extends PlainObject<T> & {
  [P in K]: T
}>(
  x: U,
): Partial<U> => {
  throw new Error ('Yet to implement !')
}
```

Is they're a way to use `K` as an array of string instead of a string? 
Something along the line of this:

```
const omit = <K extends string[]>(
  ...names: K
) => <T, U extends PlainObject<T> & {
  [P in K]: T // Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'
}>(
  x: U,
): Partial<U> => {
  throw new Error ('Yet to implement !')
}
```

The goal is to be able to have the compiler complains if a user enters a wrong object according to the key passes: `omit ('a', 'b') ({b: 3, c: 4}) // => expect error`

Thanks in advance
Seb

Comment: If `K` is an array of strings, then you want to map over `K[number]`, not `K`.  So `{[P in K[number]]: T}` should work for you, I guess.  It's hard to be 100% sure because the code doesn't seem to be a [mcve] (what is `PlainObject<T>`?  why is there a `T` and a `U` in the returned function, when `T` will almost certainly not be inferred as anything but `{}`?  what is the intended return type of the returned function?)

Comment: Sorry for that - forgot to put it, basically it's a `Record<string, T>`, and i'm using PlainObject to be able to extends it. `T` can be usefull since when an object is passed it's an object of number as values, those would be inferred without issue (I might be wrong, but based on the documentations i've red is whenever you can try to adds generics for better inference - it's not needed?) - as for U what I want is to have a PlainObject has a return object but containing some of the keys of the original object (in the implementation i put all the copied items in a `Partial<U>`

Comment: besides that your solution works just fine - if you can quickly post an answer so I can validates it it would be cool ;) Besides where can I find docs in this process of indexing tuple (as in `K[number]`) in order to better appreciates it? I see it use often on pieces of codes but still hasn't grasp it

Comment: And last but not least, instead of using `Partial U` is theyre a way of reconstructing precisely the object resulting from a call to `omit` using the key of U (which we know) for keeping only the one that aren't removed? It would be a better experience that instead of optional (and possibly missing keys) the resulting object only actual keys ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

declare function omit<K extends string>(...properties: K[]):
  <T extends Record<K, any>>(source: T) => Omit<T, K>;
```

Usage:

```
interface Foo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  brand: symbol;
}

declare const foo: Foo;

omit('age', 'name')(foo); // $ExpectType { brand: symbol }
omit('foo', 'bar')(foo);  // $ExpectError
```